# How to validate IList foreign key? Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Please help solve my problem. I want get message if textbox `TagsSites` is empty.

My models:

**Site**:

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TypeMenuId { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual IList<TagSite> TagsSites { get; set; }    
        public virtual TypeMenu TypeMenu { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

**Tag**:

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<TagSite> TagsSites { get; set; }
```

**TagSite**:

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }

        public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
```

I now get this message for all empty inputs.

[image]

How to get message "The TagsSites field is required." ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the user supposed to enter in the Tags input field ? Tag names separated by comma ?

Comment: Yes. I use bootstrap tags input

Comment: If it is a string, Why not add a string property to your view model for the string value and mark it with `[Required]` attribute ?

Comment: namely, it can not be verified? [Required]
        public virtual IList<TagSite> TagsSites { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a view model for your view with a property for a comma separated tag names and mark it with the `Required` attribute.

```
public class CreateSiteVm
{
  [Required] 
  public string Name { set;get;}
  [Required] 
  public string Description { set;get;}
  [Required] 
  public string Tags { set;get;}
  [Required] 
  public int TypeMenuId { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> TypeMenus { set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new CreateSiteVm();
  vm.TypeMenus = dbContext.TypeMenus.Select(x=> new SelectListItem { 
                                                           Value=x.Id.ToString(),
                                                           Text=x.Name}).ToList();
  return View(vm);
}
```

and in your view,

```
@model CreateSiteVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <p>@Html.ValidationSummary(false)</p>
  <label>Name</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.Name)

  <label>Descsription</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.Descsription)

  <label>Tags</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.Tags)

  <input type="submit" />
}
```

and in your HttpPost action method, create an object of your entity and set the values from view model object which is your method parameter. You can use Split method to split the comma separated string.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateSiteVm model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var e=new Site { Name = model.Name, Description = model.Description};
    e.TypeMenuId = model.TypeMenuId;

    var arr = model.Tags.Split(',');
    foreach (var s in arr)
    {
      e.Tags.Add(new Tag { Name = s});       
    }
    dbContext.Sites.Add(e);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  //to do : Load the dropdown again same as GET
  return View(model);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you may want here is the [MinLengthAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).  Implementation looks something like this.

```
[Required] 
[MinLength (1)]
public virtual  IList <TagSite> TagSites { get; set; }
```